# Link to another page on same domain, Elementor, without giving full URL

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I just started learning Elementor and wordpress.

I want to give another page URL in elementor button,  i am giving like this `/website/jobs/`, is there any way I can just give `./jobs/`.

Comment: Can you please let me know it is page,post or custom post type? so, I will give you the solution for the same.

Comment: @ZealousWeb, its a page. actualy just started learning wordpress, going through Youtube and Udemy tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

I have an Option you can use dynamic value in URL of a button either is a post or page select dynamic value.

this is not the right way to direct give ./jobs/.

Comment: hi, can you plz share some online resource URL, from where I can see, how to call dynamic URL in button.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

By `/website/jobs` I presume you mean `domain/jobs`.

If the Elementor button doesn't accept `/jobs` because it checks for a valid URL, then you will need to either try editing the element as HTML

```
<a href="/jobs" data-type="URL" data-id="/jobs">Jobs</a>
```

Or add the link to the page using ctrl+k, not in an element that checks URL validity.

The problem with using `./jobs` is that it navigates from the current directory, which may be `second-domain/blog/2022/05/07/bloggy`. If you use `./jobs` on this page, the server will have to resolve `second-domain/blog/2022/05/07/bloggy/jobs` to just `second-domain/jobs` or `domain/jobs`. Some users may click on links that return a [404 response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/404).

[Documentation](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins) can be confusing, so a `.` just means the current directory and `/` means the root folder in most command languages, like BASh and CLI.

You should just use `/jobs` or `/blog/2022/05/07/bloggy` to link these pages on a multi-domain site or a site where the links need to update dynamically when the domain changes. This works because we're modifying the client's href or [hypertext reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/href).

The client (browser) only sees the domain as the root of the server so `/` equals the domain that the client is currently looking at and `/jobs` resolves correctly.